# Viewpager with fragments creates a java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im trying to create a Viewpager with fragments.

I have 4 activities which are related to my problem.

This is the first Activity
(Viewpageractivity is the second activity):

```
package com.exple.v1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MovieActionGenreActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    LayoutInflater inflater;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        populateListView();
        registerClickCallback();

    }
    private void registerClickCallback() {

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent;
                switch(position)
                {

                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(MovieActionGenreActivity.this,ViewpagerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(MovieActionGenreActivity.this,MovieAnimationGenreActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent = new Intent(MovieActionGenreActivity.this,MovieComedyGenreActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    intent = new Intent(MovieActionGenreActivity.this,MovieDocumentaryGenreActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    intent = new Intent(MovieActionGenreActivity.this,MovieHorrorGenreActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    intent = new Intent(MovieActionGenreActivity.this,MovieDramaGenreActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void populateListView() {



        String[] textz = {"Komedi","Äventyr","Western","Drama","Thriller","Fantasy"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.the_list, textz);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_movies_maingenres,null);
        listView.addHeaderView(header,null,false);
        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText("Huvudgenrer:Action");
        TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt2.setText("Välj en genre inom Action");


    }

}
```

This activity displays a listview with a header and it is only through the first object in the list that you can access my viewpager.
(I have done this intentionally just to test it at first)

And here is my Viewpageractivity:

```
package com.exple.v1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class ViewpagerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ViewPager pager;
    ViewpagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapter = new ViewpagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



}
```

The two remaining activities are the Viewpageradapter which is the adapter 
for my viewpager, and the last one is the fragment which is called ViewpagerFragment.

Here is my adapters syntax:

```
package com.exple.v1;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class ViewpagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    int[] image = {};


    public ViewpagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ViewpagerFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 5;
    }

}
```

And here is my fragment class:

```
package com.exple.v1;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ViewpagerFragment extends Fragment{


    public ViewpagerFragment()
    {


    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And for some reason, an error message is showing up. 
Here is the entire error from the logcat:

```
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031): Process: com.exple.v1, PID: 32031
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exple.v1/com.exple.v1.ViewpagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at com.exple.v1.ViewpagerActivity.onCreate(ViewpagerActivity.java:19)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
05-02 09:05:51.580: E/AndroidRuntime(32031):    ... 11 more
```

As i have interpreted it, I should get a viewpager which should show me 5
viewpages (see adapter if you are wondering why just 5)

What have I done wrong?

Comment: show layout of activity?

Comment: is your `activity_main` layout contains `viewpager`?

Comment: activity_main does not contain a viewpager, only a listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ViewpagerActivity` you use an incorrect layout without a `ViewPager`, for this reason pager is null and you receive a `NullPointerException`.

Change the `onCreate` method of your `ViewpagerActivity` to this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpagers);

    pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    adapter = new ViewpagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```